# Azure DevOps RES API - Return Query Results for a specific release via REST Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to automate a process that is currently being done via a manual export to .csv from a Shared Query. How do I return all user stories included in a specific release via ADO REST Services? [image]

I have attached an image of the Query as a reference, and I can use this GET statement:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=7.1-preview.2`

And see the following result but looking to get all the User Stories included in a specific release.

```
{
"id": "fdb90321-9f60-45a4-9097-3dad03e8f451",
"name": "Release 1.83",
"path": "Shared Queries/AT_Eclipse/Releases/Release 1.83",
"createdDate": "2023-02-21T07:56:08.34Z",
"lastModifiedBy": {
    "id": "647073f7-a82a-63ec-90f8-2594fbec5795",
    "name": "Removed",
    "displayName": "Removed",
    "url": "Removed": {
        "avatar": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.NjQ3MDczZjctYTgyYS03M2VjLTkwZjgtMjU5NGZiZWM1Nzk1"
        }
    },
    "uniqueName": "Removed",
    "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.NjQ3MDczZjctYTgyYS03M2VjLTkwZjgtMjU5NGZiZWM1Nzk1",
    "descriptor": "aad.NjQ3MDczZjctYTgyYS03M2VjLTkwZjgtMjU5NGZiZWM1Nzk1"
},
"lastModifiedDate": "2023-03-02T06:12:13.687Z",
"queryType": "flat",
"isPublic": true,
"lastExecutedBy": {
    "id": "Removed",
    "displayName": "Removed",
    "url": "Removed": {
        "avatar": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.OGM3MTdlMWYtOGM2OS03ZjY4LWEwNzgtYjE0YzZkYWM0YmI1"
        }
    },
    "uniqueName": "Removed",
    "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.OGM3MTdlMWYtOGM2OS03ZjY4LWEwNzgtYjE0YzZkYWM0YmI1",
    "descriptor": "aad.OGM3MTdlMWYtOGM2OS03ZjY4LWEwNzgtYjE0YzZkYWM0YmI1"
},
"lastExecutedDate": "2023-03-08T16:36:31.677Z",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/7729aa8c-f280-4e74-8eec-03f3a94e0b31/_apis/wit/queries/fdb90321-9f60-45a4-9097-3dad03e8f451"
    },
    "html": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/web/qr.aspx?pguid=7729aa8c-f280-4e74-8eec-03f3a94e0b31&qid=fdb90321-9f60-45a4-9097-3dad03e8f451"
    },
    "parent": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/F{Organization}/7729aa8c-f280-4e74-8eec-03f3a94e0b31/_apis/wit/queries/989c11d5-bff0-40dd-bff3-8e9a6a99e25b"
    },
    "wiql": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/7729aa8c-f280-4e74-8eec-03f3a94e0b31/_apis/wit/wiql/fdb90321-9f60-45a4-9097-3dad03e8f451"
    }
},
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/7729aa8c-f280-4e74-8eec-03f3a94e0b31/_apis/wit/queries/fdb90321-9f60-45a4-9097-3dad03e8f451"
```

}

Comment: From my investigation, the option here is to use Queries - Get Queries Batch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get-queries-batch?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get information about your query but not running it. To run it, you may use query ID or wiql

**Query ID**

In your case: `"id": "fdb90321-9f60-45a4-9097-3dad03e8f451"`

Use it in this REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

**WIQL**

You have to know the query wiql and you may do that through the:

1. The same REST API with `$expand=wiql` option.
2. Install the following extension and copy the query wiql: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor

Then you can execute wiql through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

Comment: Thank you. This worked by dropping `{team}` from the path:

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.2

Comment: @MikeUbezzi pls, mark as an answer here to share your experience with others